# How to create a simple NLP wordmap in PHP with a JSON dictionary?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to make a wordmap.

This is my dictionary:

```
{
  "hey": "hello",
  "heya": "hello",
  "heyo": "hello",
  "hiya": "hello"
}
```

I want to make all these words "hello" with PHP.

I have tried `foreach` and `for` loops to output `hello`.

> But, the output is currently `null`

:

```
<?php
  $word = $_GET['word'];
  if (isset($word) == false) { 
    echo "Error: No word defined."; return;
  }
  $json = file_get_contents("./wordmap.json");
  $jsondata = json_decode($json, true);

  if (in_array(word, $jsondata)) {
    $newWord = "";
    $jsondatalength = count($jsondata);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $jsondatalength; $i++) {
      if ($jsondata[i] == $word) {
        echo $newWord . $jsondata[i];
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I think the issue is in this code. `if (in_array(word, $jsondata))` Try changing it to `if (in_array($word, $jsondata))`

Comment: Also review all your other variables because several are missing the dollar sign prefix.

Comment: Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` enabled, it will warn about these things.

Comment: You can't use a `for` loop like that to iterate over an associative array. Also, for indexed arrays, indexes start at `0`, not `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains several errors.

```
if (in_array(word, $jsondata)) {
```

Here there probably is a typo. This line should read:

```
if (in_array($word, $jsondata)) {
```

**But why the interpreter doesn't report the error?**

It reports it but it reports it as a notice and, by default, the interpreter is configured to not display the notices.

`word` is not a PHP variable and it is also not a PHP keyword. It is nothing, to be honest; just a four-letter word that does not mean anything in the code.
But the interpreter is forgiving and thinks you wanted to write the `"word"` string but you forgot the quotes. It triggers a notice (that is not displayed because of your configuration) and converts `word` to `"word"` and then continues the execution of the code.
Of course, the string `"word"` is not present in the array you decoded from the JSON and the `for` loop does not have any effect.

A worse error is the usage of the `for` loop to iterate over an array that is not indexed by numeric keys.

Your array is in fact a hash (aka map or dictionary); it associates strings to other strings. `$jsondata[1]` doesn't make any sense, unless `$jsondata` contains the key `1` (or `"1"`) and this does not happen.

You should use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop over `$jsondata` but you don't need to; there are other, better, ways to get a value from an associative array given you know its key or viceversa.

Another one:

```
  if ($jsondata[i] == $word) {
    echo $newWord . $jsondata[i];
  }
```

The code above prints the value of `$word` if it is equal with some other value. This means your `for` loop prints the value of `$word` zero or more times, depending on some condition. This behaviour does not have much sense and it does not match your description.

If all you want to do is to translate `"hey"` to `"hello"`, `"heya"` to `"hello"` and so on (i.e. the keys of `$jsondata` to its values) then all the code you need is:

```
// ...
$jsondata = json_decode($json, true);

echo($jsondata[$word]);
```

If the value of `$word` is a key of `$jsondata` then `$jsondata[$word]` is its associated value. Otherwise it is `null` and a notice is triggered.
If you want to write clean code (i.e. do not trigger any notices or warnings) you can use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) the value only when the `$word` is an existing key of `$jsondata`:

```
$jsondata = json_decode($json, true);

if (array_key_exists($jsondata, $word)) {
    echo($jsondata[$word]);
}
```

Btw, the value returned by [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is not a JSON ([`JSON`](http://json.org) is a string) but an object or an array (it is an array in your case because you pass `TRUE` as the second argument of `json_decode()`). This means the name of the variable (`$jsondata`) is misleading as it is not a JSON and not related to a JSON in any way.

Comment: Thank you @axiac! It works perfectly! (and yes the if statement was a typo).
I'm used to JavaScript arrays so... btw I'm new to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

In_array looks for values, not keys.
You should either do in_array on array_keys of the array or just echo the $array[$word].

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$word = "Heya";

echo $arr[strtolower($word)]; //hello
```

Of course a good thing would be to add a `if(isset($arr[strtolower($word)]))` before the echo.

Because you use in_array the way you do your code will only check if the word is empty then it will not find a match in the in_array and end.
The code inside the second if never runs.

Comment: @Emma not true. I was wrong once. It was the time I said I was wrong.

Comment: You could always change it to `echo $arr[strtolower($word)]??$word;` which will cater for the item not being found.

Comment: @NigelRen if that is what is supposed to happen if the word is not found then yes. Not sure about that though.

Answer (score 0):

By using in_array you are searching for a value.  Whereas you actually want to check if the key exists in your array, and if it does, the value will be your corresponding translation.

```
<?php
$word = $_GET['word'] ?? null;
//$word = 'hey'; // Used here for testing bypassing query params.
if (is_null($word)) {
    echo "Error: No word defined.";
    return;
}

$json=<<<JSON
{
  "hey": "hello",
  "heya": "hello",
  "heyo": "hello",
  "hiya": "hello"
}
JSON;
$translation_table = json_decode($json, true);

$translation = array_key_exists($word, $translation_table)
    ? $translation_table[$word]
    : null;
```

If the word is not found the translation will be assigned null.

Comment: What's the point of putting the JSON in the source code? If its content is known in advance then there is no need for JSON. The array produced by `json_decode()` can be used directly in the code.

Comment: There is no point other than to show the format of expected data and to run as an all-in-one example.

Comment: The JSON posted in the question is correct and the code that parses it is also correct.

Comment: Fine, I think the code is a contrite example.  I've just inlined the JSON.  This is hair splitting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$wordList = json_decode($json, true);
$translateKeys = array_keys($wordList);

$search = 'Hello';

foreach ($translateKeys as $wordKey) {

    $lastLetter = substr($wordKey, -1);

    // Considering cases of heyaaaaaaaaaa instead of heya
    if(preg_match('/^'.$wordKey. $lastLetter .'*?/i', $search)){

        $transtateFoundKey = $wordKey;
    }
}

echo $wordList[$transtateFoundKey] ?? 'No match found';
```